# web pages compression

Tags: compression, http-compression

I am new to websites compression and the ways used to do so. I want to know how to compress all page content and sources such as css, JS, images and so on. I know this could be a big topic, but the start always begin with simple questions and answers.

Do I have to compress things in specific format or there is a way how to do that?

**Update #1**

I tested some of my web pages on [the optimizer site](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/) to see how things go, but it turned out that I need a lot of content compression. so now what is the right way to do the compression on Apache?

Comment: Do you want to _serve_ compressed content, or _store_ it in compressed form?

Comment: @RolandSmith Thanks for asking. I really don't know the difference between both, but I want to make my web pages load faster and less http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean *serving* compressed content, then the standard is supporting `deflate` and `gzip`.

It is advisable to turn compression on only on textual files (HTML, script output, CSS, JS), since JPG/PNG images are already compressed and it would be unnecessary overhead for your server.

In Apache, for instance, you can use `mod_deflate`.
It allows you to specify which file types to compress, thanks to the `AddOutputFilterByType` directive.

More info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html.

Comment: Thanks @Michele. I think that code from Apache can be placed in the root .htacess, right? if so, how do I know how much the contents compressed? or at least how do I know this property works good or not. Thanks

Comment: Yes. There's an handy tool for testing HTTP compression: http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/ .

Comment: Thanks everyone for the great comment and support. I was looking around for some online compressing tools and found this http://htmlcompressor.com/compressor.html ,but I don't think it is enough because the content has to be again compressed before sending request via http or https

Answer (score 1):

Several webservers like nginx ([HttpGzipModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule)) and apache ([mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html)) can compress content before serving it. Don't enable compression on stuff that is probably already compressed, like photos, music, videos, software archives et cetera.

Comment: Thanks again @Roland. well, I have Apache so I think I can use mod_deflate as you mentioned. so I think you mean I should add mod_deflate code to root .htaccess to make whatever I want compressed, right?

Comment: Add it to your configuration as shown on the mod_deflate page I linked to.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that and see how things go. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There are is ways to faster loading of web-page:

1. Minimizing weight of web-page

   - Compression HTML (Gzip or deflate)
   - Compression JS (Minimizing JS + Gzip)
   - Compression CSS (Gzip)
2. Minimizing count of DNS-queries (combining CSS, JS, using sprites for icons and big sets of small images)
3. Lazy loading of JS and images

Static pages, css, js compression depends from your server configuration.

Comment: Thanks @zoonman. This is too general what you stated. I mean what tools I can use to do that. It is great you mentioned Lazy loading, but still I guess there is a better way.

Comment: Lazy load depends from your page or site. For example, you can load lightweight basic site's functional and lazyloader which make his work in background. When everything will be loaded, you enable full functionality.

If you want to control loading of your scripts, you can call some function from the end of your script.